# Javafx update database with tableview

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, tableview

I have create a script that will create and populate data to tableview (i've used scene builder for tableview). it's column is dynamic depending on the number of columns of mysql table. But I can't find any solutions on how to edit/insert data to tableview and automatically update the MySQL table.

here is my code  for dynamic columns and populating data from database to it. By the way, database table I am using has 50 columns.

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        c = DBConnect.connect();
        //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF CUSTOMER
        String SQL = "SELECT * from CAM_ODS_TIMESHEET_RAW_MOD";
        //ResultSet
        ResultSet rs = c.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        /**
         * ********************************
         * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY * 
         * ********************************
         */
        for (int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
            //We are using non property style for making dynamic table
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1));
            col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
                }
            });

            tableview.getColumns().addAll(col);

            System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
        }

        /**
         * ******************************
         * Data added to ObservableList * 
         * ******************************
         */
        while (rs.next()) {
            //Iterate Row
            ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                //Iterate Column
                if (rs.getString(i) == null) {
                    row.add("");
                } else {
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Row [1] added " + row);
            data.add(row);

        }

        //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
        tableview.setItems(data);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
```

I've also seen multiple examples that uses Model like Person class etc but I am wondering how can I use that for multiple columns like 50 columns

Thank you in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your requirement like do a fx gui of MYSQL table.
if you want to do it, you need add a changlistener for the obserbleList and add the SQL insert/update/delete logic into it.

```
ObservableList.addListener(ListChangeListener<? super E> listener)
```